# Hibernate convert existing Integer[] to String[] (bytea) in Postgres database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using Spring, Hibernate and Postgres.
In one of my model class I have:

```
@Entity
class SomeData {
    private Long dataId;
    private String name;
    private Integer[] data;
}
```

It is already used and I have data in database in above format.

"data" field is a bytea (visible in phppgadmin) type, one of the example values saved in db is:

```
��ur[Ljava.lang.Integer;������xpsr...
```

Problem is that now I need to change model to

```
String[] data;
```

But when I do that Hibernate can't read those data because it has type Integer.

My question - is it possible to convert somehow these Integer array objects to String array objects? Using some db tool, sql query or Hibernate?

Comment: maybe this can help? http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: or inside your ``setData()`` method, include logic to convert ``Integer[]`` to ``String[]``

Comment: @DonaldWu but my problem is that multiple entries already saved in database are in Integer array type and how to convert them to String array type?

Comment: The question is why are you storing serialized Java objects in the first place? That is almost always a bad idea. It would be much better to store that as a `int[]` in Postgres or `text[]`  - that way you can also use SQL to manipulate the data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't write the original code, I'm just changing it to new format. So what do you think I should use instead of String[] ?

Comment: @user3626048 Do you use some kind of migration tool for changing the schema (f.ex. liquibase, flyway, etc.)? Also, do you insist the new type to be `String[]`? (Instead of proper normalization, f.ex. `@ElementCollection` on a `List<String>`?)

Comment: @pozs I'm not using any tool but I can use if it helps. I though about ElementCollection but it will create another table in db, wouldn't it unneccesary complicate db structure? Each array has 7 or 9 entries and I save single SomeData object approx. 1 per second.

Comment: @user3626048 If you don't have such a tool, you can only change your schema with custom scripts you write and execute them by hand. You'll need some java code to read serialized values from the table, you have no other options left. -- Yes, normalization sometimes needs more table, but that only makes your structure more clear, not complicated. Complicated is rather your current situation, because the lack of normalization.

Comment: @pozs ok, thanks for your answer. Could you tell me wouldn't separate table with millions of entries work slower than serialized array object?

Comment: @user3626048 that depends on your actual data and how you usually query it. You should measure it, but usually slow queries can be improved (while with serialized objects, you literally cannot do anything with them in the database).

Comment: @pozs I'm only save it once and after only getting from db. Not updating or anything else. When I'm getting it I always need there values in arrays (like FetchType.EAGER with List),

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a conversion algorithm to run once. Something like:

```
Connection c = ((SessionImplementor)entitymanager).connection();
boolean oldstate = c.getAutoCommit();
c.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement s = c.createStatement();
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE my_table SET data = ? WHERE id = ?");
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT id, data FROM my_table");
ByteArrayInputStream bais;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectInputStream ois;
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
while (rs.next()) {
    long id = rs.getLong(1);
    byte[] bdata = rs.getBytes(2);
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bdata);
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    Integer[] olddata = (Integer[]) ois.readObject();
    String[] newdata = new String[olddata.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < olddata.length; i++) {
        Integer din = olddata[i];
        String dout = null;
        if (din != null) {
            dout = din.toString();
        }
        newdata[i] = dout;
    }
    oos.writeObject(newdata);
    oos.flush();
    ps.setLong(1, id);
    ps.setBytes(2, baos.toByteArray());
    baos.reset();
}
c.commit();
c.setAutoCommit(oldstate);
```

If you want to do it through Hibernate, you'd need a secondary column, or you'd have to change it to `Object[]`, run the conversion, then change it to `String[]`, but that's not convenient for update on production, nor is it efficient, as you'd go through a lot of layers of validations and conversions inside Hibernate.

However, if you choose to use array types inside the database itself, I have a standalone module currently proposed that allows for it https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1499 . We don't have test-cases that don't work with it, but if you can find any that need fixing, that would help with getting it approved.